# Getting an error when upgrading Laravel from 5.5 to 5.6

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to upgrade my Laravel 5.5 application to Laravel 5.6. To that end, I've been following [the upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade).

**composer.json**:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1.3",
        "encore/laravel-admin": "1.5.*",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~4.0",
        "intervention/image": "^2.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
        "laravel/passport": "^5.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "nesbot/carbon": "^1.22",
        "sebdesign/laravel-state-machine": "^1.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "laravel/homestead": "^5.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~7.0",
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0"
    },
}
```

But when I use `composer update`, I get the following error:

```
problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v4.0.8
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.6.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.2, v5.6.3, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9].
```

I tried removing the `vendor` directory and re-running `composer update`, but it still doesn't work.

How would I fix this?

Comment: What version of php do you have?

Comment: Can you show us the *whole* output of the "problem 1" section? There should be more info there.

Comment: what about `composer update laravel/framework`. what does `composer why-not symfony/process:4.0.8` output? and is this the complete error output?

Comment: For starters, one of your dependency `encore/laravel-admin` only seems to support up to `Laravel >= 5.5.0`

Comment: @SimonR My php version is 7.2.3

Comment: @NormanM This is not the complete error output. It's more than 30K characters

Comment: @B.Godoak The provided error output doesn't actually give enough information to tell you/us where the problem lies; I'd advise either adding it into the question (if it'll fit) or creating a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) with the full error output and adding the link to that gist to the question.

Comment: @Latheesan That's not a problem; 5.6 is definitely greater than or equal to 5.5 ;)

Comment: @B.Godoak that is no problem i have seen longer composer "errors". at least please put also the last part here

Answer (score 2):

You need to upgrade your `laravel/homestead` to 6.x or 7.x line. 5.x does not support Symfony 4, which is required by Laravel 5.6.

```
"require-dev": {
    "laravel/homestead": "^6.6",
    ...
},
```

For problems like that you should actually try to read these 30k chars - all you need is there:

> - laravel/homestead v5.1.0 requires symfony/process ~2.3|~3.0 /.../
> - laravel/framework v5.6.0 requires symfony/process ~4.0 /.../

Comment: To further clarify, only laravel/homestead 6.6.0+ adds the requirement for symfony/process ~4.0. I'd suggest changing this to `"laravel/homestead": "^6.6"` or going to 7.0 altogether (`"laravel/homestead": "^7.0"`)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some dependencies aren't updated or not supported by laravel 5.6.

Follow this video guide to upgrade from [laravel 5.5 to 5.6 by Jeffery way](https://youtu.be/D7wyP-1xBwg)

Comment: Please put all relevant information into your answer, don't put them on external pages or link to them only